# Solving an equation involving $x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have come to a question with the equation:

$$6 = x^2 -7x + 6.$$

The answer is $7$.

How do I do I find the solution to a problem involving $x^2$?

Comment: $0$ also works.  Try bringing the terms containing $x$ to one side and factoring it.

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting six from both sides leaves $$x^2 - 7x = 0.$$ Now note that both terms on the left hand side have contain $x$ so we can take it out as a common factor like this: $$x(x - 7) = 0.$$ Now, we use the null factor law that tells us that if the product of two things is zero, at least one of them is zero. Therefore we must have $x = 0$ or $x - 7 = 0$ (i.e. $x = 7$).

So the solutions to $x^2 - 7x + 6 = 6$ are $x = 0$ and $x = 7$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The $6$'s cancel out, then factoring out $x$ leaves you with  $$x^2-7x=0 \implies x(x-7)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

If you ever get stuck and can't apply the methods here, there is a more general solution.  If

$$Ax^2+Bx+C=0$$
then 
$$x=\frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$

In this case

$$x^2 - 7x=0$$  implies that

$$x=\frac{7 \pm \sqrt{49-4(1)(0)}}{2(1)}=\frac{7 \pm \sqrt{49}}{2}=\frac{7 \pm 7}{2}=$$

which equals $0$ or $(7+7)/2=7$

Comment: Let me add a qualifier to this answer....  This is often the more time consuming way to do it, and occasionally its much easier to do what the others did.  Plus if you use this technique only, you may find yourself not thinking when you do these sorts of problems.